# How independently import files in values.yaml

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm using the [prometheus stack](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack) project to implement via helm with kubernetes, but I would like to customize some rules. I'm trying to use the `additionalPrometheusRules` parameter for this, but I'm facing syntax errors inside it, here's my structure:

```
../module-prometheus-helm
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
├── rules
│   └── customrules.yaml
├── templates
│   └── configmap.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

File: customrules.yaml

```
additionalPrometheusRules:
 - name: my-rule-file
   groups:
     - name: my_group
       rules:
       - record: my_record
         expr: 100 * my_record
```

File: configmap.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-receiver-configmap
data:
    {{ $currentScope := . }}
    {{ range $path, $_ :=  .Files.Glob  "rules/**.yaml" }}
    {{- with $currentScope}}
{{ base $path }}: |-
{{ .Files.Get $path | indent 2 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{ end }}
```

File values.yaml is [default helm](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack).

Output Error

```
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(ConfigMap): unknown field "customrules.yaml" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap
helm.go:84: [debug] error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(ConfigMap): unknown field "customrules.yaml" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap
```

How can I independently import the additional rules into the repository without polluting the `values.yaml` file?

Comment: This is a very common helm-ism; you have your `{{` flush with the leading edge of the file but the generated file must still be legal yaml after the template is done with it. You almost have it with your `| indent 2` but that will merely indent the _value_, nothing is indenting the _key_. Then, after you fix the key indent, you'll need to up that `indent` value to be 2 more than whatever you indent the key by.

Comment: For the `additionalPrometheusRules` you are trying to set, I noticed this in the docs "## Deprecated way to provide custom recording or alerting rules to be deployed into the cluster.". It seems you should be using `additionalPrometheusRulesMap` now.

Comment: I am not really understanding the expecrtation where the configmap becomes `additionalPrometheusRules` as values for a different helm chart? flux has this support but default helm does not.

Comment: I'm thinking of using terraform, it seems that the helm is not prepared to receive this in this parameter